# Fixing GCM 1000 message limit, help loop script

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

I am using PHP to send GCM notification to users. Based on their token saved in SQL on server. But I have a limit of 1000 notifications at once to send,

this is my working code , now i need to edit it to loop the process, and send 5000 notification in sections, 1000 than 1000 etc.

Here is my PHP code, and a simple HTML I didn't post here,

```
        <?php

        $mysqlHost = "";
        $mysqlUser = "";
        $mysqlPwd = ";
        $mysqlDbname = "";


        class GCM {
        function __construct(){}

        public function send_notification($registatoin_ids,$data) {

    // GOOGLE API KEY
    define("GOOGLE_API_KEY","************");
    $url="https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send";
    $fields=array(
        "registration_ids"=>$registatoin_ids,
        "data"=>$data,
    );
    //var_dump($fields);
    $headers=array(
        "Authorization: key=".GOOGLE_API_KEY,
        "Content-Type: application/json"
    );
    $ch=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,json_encode($fields));
    $result_gcm=curl_exec($ch);
    if($result_gcm===FALSE){
        die("Curl failed: ".curl_error($ch));
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    //echo $result_gcm;
    }
    }



    // Create connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect($mysqlHost, $mysqlUser, $mysqlPwd, $mysqlDbname);

    // Check connection
    if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }


    $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE users_android_token IS                   NOT NULL AND users_android_token <> ''");

    $android_tokens = array();
    $x=0;

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     $android_tokens[] = $row["users_android_token"];
$x++;
}
    } else {
echo "0 results";
    }
    $conn->close();

    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $msg = $_POST['message'];
    $link = $_POST['link'];

    if ($android_tokens != array()) {
$gcm=new GCM();
$data=array("title"=>$title,"description"=>$msg,"link"=>$link);
$result_android=$gcm->send_notification($android_tokens,$data);
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by ***fix***?

Comment: I mean how to increase number, i now it can be done with looping process, sending every 1000 notification in sections, not at once. But i don know how to do it correctly

Comment: I see. Unfortunately, 1000 is the maximum (regardless if you use GCM/FCM) and the only way to do it is implementing a loop.

Comment: yes i know , that it way i posted question here, i need help in looping it

Comment: Okay. You modified the title, that's better. The initial title was confusing.

Comment: yes, i have found some solution here on stack, but can not seem to implement them in my code

Answer (score 0):

Rather than send notification by registrationId, why not using send notification by topic. You only need to make client subscribed to certain topic.

in GCM, you can send notification topic with this code :

```
function send_notification_topic($topicname, $message){
    $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
    $fields = array(
         'to' => '/topics/' . $topicname,
         'data' => $message
        );

    $headers = array(
         'Authorization: key=AIzablablablayourServerKey',
         'Content-Type: application/json'
        );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if($result === FALSE){
        die('Curl failed : ' . curl_error($ch));
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: there you only need to change fcm to gcm :)

Comment: never mind, i think how ever you send notification, google gcm limit is 1000 per connection, so you can not send more then 1000 at once, need to divide them in section

Comment: you have misunderstood mister, 1000 is at once simultanously, so, if you have 1 million member it will need 1000 seconds to reach all user. I think thats fair enough.

Comment: google is not stupid, there is noway they have feature that can only reach 1000 member right?

Comment: yes but you need to loop the connection, for example I have 2000 regid, and i send notification through my panel, it will say 1000 not send, and only 1000 users will receive my notification. other 1000 nothing. So need to split 2000 users in a 2 time sending and connecting gcm. And so on if a number is > 1000.

Comment: Trust me i have tried, it is not up to google, but my script. you can find similar problems all over stack site, it allows only 1000 send notes per one connection to gcm, through your API.

Comment: Many of the limitations applied to GCM and FCM are there to prevent abuse, if you need to send messages and the 1000 per request limit is to small then Topics is an alternative where you can send to all subscribers with one request.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for divided your tokens .

```
if ($android_tokens != array()) {
$gcm  = new GCM();
$data = array("title" => $title,"description" => $msg,"link" => $link);

//Divide array into 1000 tokens
$splitTokens = array_chunk($android_tokens, 1000);

//loop the array
//Obs: for looping notification may push slow 

foreach($splitTokens as $tokens) {
    $result_android = $gcm -> send_notification($tokens,$data);
}

}
```

For divide GCM may push the notification slow . it take up to 2 - 10 mins.